# Destination URL not reset. The URL returned from login must be set in the SforceService

Tags: soap, java

I am still a little new to web services and could use some help. Currently I am going through some code that was implemented before I started at this company. The code is trying to connect to salesforce to grab some of the content that we have stored there. When I run it on my local it works fine but when I switch it over to DEV environment it runs into issues. I get a:

**Cannot Set LoginResult.serverUrl – UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION: Destination URL not reset. The URL returned from login must be set in the SforceService**

I have searched previous answers and searched throughout the web but I can't find an example that goes about it the same way that it is implement at my company. The examples I find are either simple or use different methods.

Does anything jump out of the screen when you see this code that could possibly be wrong? Thanks in advance

```
protected void login() throws UnexpectedErrorFault, InvalidIdFault, LoginFault, FileNotFoundException {

    loginResult = soap.login(salesforceAuthorization.getUsername(),
                salesforceAuthorization.getPassword() + salesforceAuthorization.getToken());

    if (loginResult == null) {
            LOG.error("Could not login in to salesforce!");
            return;
        }

    SforceService sforceService = new SforceService(ResourceUtils.getURL(wsdlLocation), new QName(
                "urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com", "SforceService"));
        setSoap(sforceService.getSoap());

    final BindingProvider bindingProvider = ((BindingProvider) soap);
    final Map<String, Object> requestContext = bindingProvider.getRequestContext();
        requestContext.put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, loginResult.getServerUrl());

        final Map<String, List<String>> httpHeaders = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        requestContext.put(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS, httpHeaders);

        //Set our login session id into the session header
        final SessionHeader sessionHeader = new SessionHeader();
        sessionHeader.setSessionId(loginResult.getSessionId());

        //Configure jaxb context for the header (note: this is separate from the
        // contact that should already be initialized as part of the client impl)
        final JAXBContext jaxbContext;
        try {
            jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.sforce.soap.enterprise");
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            throw new WebServiceException(e);
        }

        final List<Header> headers = new ArrayList<Header>(1);
        final Header sessionIdHeader = new Header(new QName("urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com",           "SessionHeader"), "SessionHeader",
                new JAXBDataBinding(jaxbContext));
        sessionIdHeader.setObject(sessionHeader);
        headers.add(sessionIdHeader);

        requestContext.put(Header.HEADER_LIST, headers);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call the [login()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_login.htm) SOAP API method it returns a [LoginResult](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_login_loginresult.htm).

There are two important parts you need from the LoginResult. The `SessionId` is fairly straight forward as the unique ID for you session that needs to be included with each subsequent request to show you are logged in.

The other part is the `serverUrl`. This is the endpoint that all subsequent requests using the session ID should be sent to. The Session ID will only be valid if sent to that URL.

In theory the following line should be handling this:

```
requestContext.put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, loginResult.getServerUrl());
```

However, that doesn't appear to be passing along the required details. Try something like:

```
sforceService.endpoint_x = loginResult.getServerUrl();
```

The exact solution will depend on how `SforceService` was generated from the WSDL.